# Customize Kendo MVC Column Sorting

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can I customize sorting for a specific column on Kendo MVC?
I've been trying to use a similar code to the one in this page: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBoundColumnSortableBuilder but is not working for me. Not sure if is the Kendo Version but `Compare()` is not recognized in my code, I only want to customize the sorting for column "Project #"

Here you can see an screenshot of my code:
[image]

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think `Compare` is available to use with the MVC wrapper. I haven't been able to find any documentation for it at least. Take a look at this [thread](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-sort-compare) from the Telerik forums, it might help you out. Basically add a `ProjectNumberSort` property to the model and in the grid use `columns.Bound(c => c.ProjectNumberSort).ClientTemplate("#=ProjectNumber#");`. Have the `ProjectNumberSort` property contain values that are sorted properly and use a client template to display `ProjectNumber`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there was a request to a method in the backend where the data is written, I did the sorting in the backend instead of the frontend. Was able to find this request using the Network tab of the Dev Tools.